# Copilot and OpenAI Python script debugging

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, csv, youtube

**Update:**

As of this current posting, I do have `ids=ids` in the fuction in question, however when changing that to be `id=ids`, I get the same errors. Perhaps by viewing the full code, it may make it more obvious as to why this is happening.

Here's full code:

```
#Write a script that writes a csv file with a list of the top most viewed YouTube videos.
#The script should take a YouTube API key as an argument and use it to query the YouTube Data API for the topmost viewed videos.
#The script should then write the video title, video view count, and video ID to a csv file.
#The script should also print the total number of views to a file.

import csv
import os
import argparse
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Set DEVELOPER_KEY to the API key value from the APIs & auth > Registered apps
# tab of
#   https://cloud.google.com/console
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
DEVELOPER_KEY = "---hidden---"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

def youtube_search(options):
  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

  # Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
  # query term.
  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=options.q,
    part="id,snippet",
    maxResults=options.max_results
  ).execute()

  ids = [item["id"]["videoId"] for item in search_response["items"]]

  search_response = youtube.videos().list(
    part="statistics",
    ids=ids
  ).execute()

  videos_with_view_counts = [[item["id"], item["statistics"]["viewCount"]] for item in search_response["items"]]

  return videos_with_view_counts

  # Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
  # matching videos, channels, and playlists.
  for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
    if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
      videos.append(search_result)

  return videos

def main():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Search on YouTube')
  parser.add_argument("--q", help="Search term", default="Google")
  parser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=25)
  args = parser.parse_args()

  try:
    os.remove('top_videos.csv')
  except OSError:
    pass

  with open('top_videos.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['title', 'viewCount', 'videoId']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for video in youtube_search(args):  # video is a dictionary
      print("Title: %s" % video['snippet']['title'])  # Print video title
      print("View Count: %s" % video['statistics']['viewCount'])  # video['statistics']['viewCount']
      print("Video ID: %s" % video['id']['videoId'])  # videoId
      print("\n")  # blank line

      writer.writerow({'title': video['snippet']['title'], 'viewCount': video['statistics']['viewCount'], 'videoId': video['id']['videoId']})

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

The errors I got from ((your code + Copilot's code)) are below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\brian\Documents\GitHub\scripts\top-youtube.py", line 75, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\brian\Documents\GitHub\scripts\top-youtube.py", line 66, in main
    for video in youtube_search(args):  # video is a dictionary
  File "c:\Users\brian\Documents\GitHub\scripts\top-youtube.py", line 31, in youtube_search
    ids = [item["id"]["videoId"] for item in search_response["items"]]
  File "c:\Users\brian\Documents\GitHub\scripts\top-youtube.py", line 31, in <listcomp>
    ids = [item["id"]["videoId"] for item in search_response["items"]]
KeyError: 'videoId'
```

I suspect that other parts of the code are causing the problem, not the function itself. I am not opposed to cutting anything out of the script necessary to make it search all of YouTube and return a list of the top say 1000 videos in ascending order weighted by views, likes, subs in that order. If that is indeed YouTube's algorithm for how they calculate rewards for content creators. My idea is to use this information to start creating channels that can earn passive income, no matter how small, that can then through the use of Python and APIs be funneled into my exchange accounts to then be traded by Python trading bots.

Anything from a YouTube channel is better than nothing. I also know about the fact that you can funnel traffic to your YouTube videos/channels from websites and social media accounts. Not looking to get rich off of YouTube, looking to create a steady trickle of currency that can then be traded. YouTube is not expected to do the bulk of the heavy lifting here, just to be a source among possibly many. So, my idea is to use this script initially to get ideas for channels and videos, content, and success rates. If you know a better way to do this, please let me know.

The full script is [here](https://github.com/brianbills21/scripts/blob/master/top-youtube.py).

Answer (score 1):

```
2. Create a new project.
```

> But when I login to the dev console there's nothing there about creating a new project.

It seems that you missed the `Select a project` button at the top-left of the [Google Developers Console](https://console.cloud.google.com).

[image: Select a project]

## Update:

To use retrieved ids from YouTube Data API v3 [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint to pass them to [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) in order to get their statistics (notably their `viewCount`s) use instead of your code snippet:

```
  # Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
  # query term.
  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=options.q,
    part="id,snippet",
    maxResults=options.max_results
  ).execute()

  ids = [item["id"]["videoId"] for item in search_response["items"]]

  search_response = youtube.videos().list(
    part="statistics",
    ids=ids
  ).execute()

  videos_with_view_counts = [[item["id"], item["statistics"]["viewCount"]] for item in search_response["items"]]
```

Comment: Okay @Benjamin Loison, I'll go back and check again. Thanks. If you wouldn't mind, can you show me how to modify the print statements in the second script? Thanks.

Comment: To get the `viewCount` you need to call [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with `part=statistics` in addition to current call to [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

Comment: Thank you so much @Benjamin Loison, I'll check it tomorrow and I'll bet it works. I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi @Benjamin Loison, I added to the original post if you have a minute.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi @Benjamin Loison, I think we're getting closer, and thank you so much for your awesome help. If you have a couple spare cycles and you wouldn't mind, I updated my original post. Thanks again. And btw, I only need the csv file, it's not necessary to print to terminal or txt file.

Comment: On my side, your code works well if change `ids=ids` to `id=ids`. May you give the full code snippet to be able to reproduce the issue? Especially provide the `options.q` and `options.maxResults` values.

Comment: Hi @Benjamin Loison, I hope I did what you asked, perhaps I should have put some print statements in the code to give you what you asked for? Not sure, but I hope this helps you to decipher the cause of the issue. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry but I won't help you anymore as your code is full of inconsistencies that you don't seem to try to solve on your own (I already mentioned `id=ids` [as the documentation of `Videos: list`, that I already sent you, describe](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id), **there is dead code in your `youtube_search` function as there are two returns without any condition on the first one**, you filter `youtube#video` after calling `Search: list`, while this latter takes as argument only videos (and not channels for instance) and same thing for `Videos: list`,

Comment: you don't provide `snippet` as a `part` while *you* use the `snippet` result in your `main` function). So my bad I haven't ever worked with such *AI* generated code (if you haven't modified it much) and I thought you would read the code, understand it, check it and so on, but it's not the case.

Comment: I did try id=ids and the output were a set of errors much the same as the ones I got with ids=ids. And as I said, yes, I do not understand everything that's happening in the rest of the code. I noticed that too, the for loop is dead as Copilot makes it show up as dimmed in Visual Studio Code. Okay, I'm sorry if I wasted your time or made you angry and thank you for the help that you did give me.